# Why isn't my for loop in Javascript changing the variable amount?

Tags: javascript

I made a Javascript code that should take two numbers in an array, arrange them from lowest to highest, and then return the sum of every number between and including them. So sumAll(1, 4) // returns the sum of 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 which is 10. However, when I do it, my variable total does not change from 0 with my for loop.

```
var sumAll = function(arr) {
   var lower = Math.min(arr[0], arr[1]);
   var upper = Math.max(arr[0], arr[1]);

   var total = 0;

   for (var i = lower; i <= upper; i++) {
    total += i;
    }
return total;
}
```

This code should return 10 when using 1 and 4, but it gives 0 because var total = 0. When I manually change var total to equal 10, then it turns to ten, which means my for loop is not working the way it should, and I have no idea why. Any help is greatly appreciated, I am super new to coding and have been working on this for a while.

Also, this is a TDD project so it is attached to a spec js file. So the only other part of this code is not actually me calling the array but

```
module.exports = sumAll
```

The spec file asks for this:

```
var sumAll = require('./sumAll')
describe('sumAll', function() {
  it('sums numbers within the range', function() {
expect(sumAll(1, 4)).toEqual(10);
  });
```

Comment: How are you **calling** the function? *edit* oh I see it now. Well because your function expects an array, the call should be `sumAll([1, 4])`.

Comment: show your input, what is inside `arr`?

Comment: I've just run it into the console in my browser and it returns 10. Can you post the code calling the function?

Comment: Your shown code looks fine but we need to see how you call it as as well as see what is `arr` ? What are the values for `arr[0]` and `arr[1]`? Do a  `console.log(arr[0]);console.log(arr[1]);` to see what values you have.

Comment: 2 bucks ( in euros ) say he is not calling the func with an arra [1,4], but with 2 different params, (1,4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in your question works well, however, if you still have issues you could try this:

```
function sumAll(n1, n2) {
  var numbers = [];
  numbers.length = Math.abs(n2-n1)+1; numbers.fill(0);
  numbers = numbers.map((i, j) => (Math.min(n1,n2)+j))
  return numbers.reduce((acc, i) => (acc+=i))
}

sumAll(1,4); //10
```